# pytz utc conversion

Tags: python, datetime, utc, pytz

What is the right way to convert a naive time and a `tzinfo` into an UTC time?
Say I have:

```
d = datetime(2009, 8, 31, 22, 30, 30)
tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
```

First way, pytz inspired:

```
d_tz = tz.normalize(tz.localize(d))
utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
d_utc = d_tz.astimezone(utc)
```

Second way, from [UTCDateTimeField](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/388/)

```
def utc_from_localtime(dt, tz):
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)
    _dt = tz.normalize(dt)
    if dt.tzinfo != _dt.tzinfo:
        # Houston, we have a problem...
        # find out which one has a dst offset
        if _dt.tzinfo.dst(_dt):
            _dt -= _dt.tzinfo.dst(_dt)
        else:
            _dt += dt.tzinfo.dst(dt)
    return _dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Needless to say those two methods produce different results for quite a few timezones.

Question is - what's the right way?

Comment: I am amazed that nobody deleted 'Thanks' from the body of the question. Let's see how long it takes to get it removed!

Comment: By my calculations, only 897 days.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your first method seems to be the approved one, and should be DST-aware.

You could shorten it a tiny bit, since *pytz.utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')*, but you knew that already :)

```
tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
def toUTC(d):
    return tz.normalize(tz.localize(d)).astimezone(pytz.utc)

print "Test: ", datetime.datetime.utcnow(), " = ", toUTC(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Why normalize()? is it really necessary?

Comment: @kolypto: Apparently `tz.normalize()` will accounts for Daylight Savings Time and other nuisances that `tz.localize()` doesn't, as explained in other SO answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379874/147320).

Comment: @kolypto: some local times do not exist e.g., when the local clock jumps forward in Spring during the transition to summer time in some countries (northern hemisphere). `tz.localize()` respects given `d` object (it doesn't change the time, it only tries to add an appropriate tzinfo object) therefore `tz.normalize()` is necessary to adjust non-existing times. Though both times (before/after the adjustment) should correspond to the same UTC time i.e., `tz.normalize()` might be unnecessary if all we do is converting the time to UTC as in this case.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the right way to convert a naive time and a tzinfo into an utc time?

[This answer enumerates some issues with converting a local time to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163706/4279):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

d = datetime(2009, 8, 31, 22, 30, 30)
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')

# a) raise exception for non-existent or ambiguous times
aware_d = tz.localize(d, is_dst=None)
## b) assume standard time, adjust non-existent times
#aware_d = tz.normalize(tz.localize(d, is_dst=False))
## c) assume DST is in effect, adjust non-existent times
#aware_d = tz.normalize(tz.localize(naive_d, is_dst=True))

# convert to UTC
utc_d = aware_d.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it incorporates details about the DST option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first method. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel of timezone conversion

Answer (score -2):

```
    import pytz
    from django.utils import timezone

    tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    time = tz.normalize(timezone.now())
```

Comment: it is incorrect. If `USE_TZ=True` then `timezone.now()` returns an aware datetime in UTC and therefore you should not call `tz.normalize()` on it. If `USE_TZ=False` then django uses default timezone that may be different from America/Los_Angeles and the code is wrong in this case too.