# date time localize does not acount for DST

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have created a 4pm datetime object this way:

```
dt = pytz.timezone('America/New_York').localize(datetime(1970, 1, 1, hour=16))
```

Now I am replacing the day month and year:

```
newDt = dt.replace(year=2019, month=7, day=23)
```

printing the newDt object yields, which is odd because its -4 GMT today:

```
2019-07-23 16:00:00-05:00
```

Is there a way to force the recalculation for the DST offset?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Somehow it seems to be related to the timezone itself. Just like `pytc.utc` is different to `'Europe/London'`, in this case `'America/New_York'` is not the same as `'US/Eastern'`.</s>

```py
newDt = dt.replace(year=2019, month=7, day=23) #2019-07-23 16:00:00-05:00
newDt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))  #2019-07-23 17:00:00-04:00
```

However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) they should behave the exact same way.

**CORRECTION**

My answer above does not seem to be right.

Apparently the issue seems to be related to some odd behavior from the `replace` function, where it does not carry the *dst* information if the original date was not during the daylight saving period. Some people have mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace).

You would need to re-localize that date using `astimezone`

```py
print (newDt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York')))

Out[14]:
2019-07-23 17:00:00-04:00
```