# pytz giving wrong timezone offset for 'Africa/Khartoum'

Tags: python, timezone, timezone-offset, pytz

I have the following code

```
import datetime
import pytz

tz_offset = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Africa/Khartoum' or 'GMT')).strftime('%z')
print(tz_offset)
```

The expected output is "+0200" but it gives "+0300".

Since pytz gets its info from IANA, I contacted them and they said it is correctly set in their database. Here is their email reply:

> On 6/19/20 10:40 AM, Ubay Abdelgadir wrote:
>
> > Khartoum's time zone is +2 since 1/Nov/2017. I think it is wrong in the
> > IANA database:
> >
> > ```
> > Zone Africa/Khartoum 2:10:08 - LMT 1931
> >     2:00 Sudan CA%sT 2000 Jan 15 12:00
> >     3:00 - EAT 2017 Nov  1
> >     2:00 - CAT
> > ```
>
> That data entry says that Africa/Khartoum has been +02 since 2017 Nov
> 1, so it appears to agree .with your statement that Khartoum's time
> zone is +2 since 1/Nov/2017.

**Edit**

I solved this by updating pytz version, it was 2016.7 which is outdated for my case (change happened in 2017)

Comment: Does [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/5987) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the example for `datetime.datetime.now`. `pytz` also shows the correct UTC offset change in 2017 for the timezone 'Africa/Khartoum'. However, you need to use the [`localize`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) method (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace)).

```
import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Africa/Khartoum')

# correct UTC offset for "now":
tz_offset = tz.localize(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%z')
print(tz_offset)
# +0200

# also correct UTC offset around 1st Nov 2017:
tz_offset = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2017,10,31)).strftime('%z')
print(tz_offset)
# +0300
tz_offset = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2017,11,1)).strftime('%z')
print(tz_offset)
# +0200
```

If you don't `localize`, you only get the [local mean time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html). With `dateutil`, you would not have to localize and could implement the timezone directly:

```
import dateutil
tz = dateutil.tz.gettz('Africa/Khartoum')
tz_offset = datetime.datetime(2017,10,31, tzinfo=tz).strftime('%z')
print(tz_offset)
# +0300
tz_offset = datetime.datetime(2017,11,1, tzinfo=tz).strftime('%z')
print(tz_offset)
# +0200
```

Comment: I tried this in my laptop, didn't work. But tried it on an online testing website https://repl.it and it worked!

Comment: Strangely, the above pytz code didn't work on my laptop (all offsets where +0300), but worked in an online testing website.

Comment: @ObayAbd-Algader: that is strange... for reference: I'm using Python 3.8.2 x64 on Windows 10 with pytz 2020.1.

Comment: Yes. I just found that my pytz version was 2016.7 which is outdated for my case. After I updated the module it your code worked fine.

Comment: @ObayAbd-Algader: very good. I'd suggest not to use `pytz` anyway unless you need compatibility with older scripts or Python2. For now, `dateutil` is in my eyes the better option (e.g. has no "`localize` trap"). In the future, Python 3.9 will have the [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) module, so timezone functionality will be build-in (no 3rd party packages needed anymore).

Comment: Good news about the zoneinfo module. If I hand control over which library is used I would switch to dateutil, the problem occurred to me while using Odoo.