# Datetime Timezones from String

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to figure out how to make a datetime object aware through using a variable. I grab the timezone of the user and pass it through a form to be used.

I have tried both of the below methods and am not having much success

```py
timezone_variable = "Europe/London"
new_datetime = datetime(int(date_year), int(date_month), int(date_day),
                            int(time_hour), int(date_minute), tzinfo=timezone_variable)

new_datetime = datetime(int(date_year), int(date_month), int(date_day),
                            int(time_hour), int(date_minute), tzinfo=timezone.timezone_variable)
```

This will then give me errors of `TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'`

The timezone will not always be known upfront, so it would not be possible to simply have the argument be as such `tzinfo=timezone.utc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or Python 3.9's [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html):

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz
# from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9

date_year, date_month, date_day, time_hour, date_minute = 2020, 10, 21, 10, 21

timezone_variable = gettz("Europe/London") # ZoneInfo("Europe/London") # Python 3.9

new_datetime = datetime(int(date_year), int(date_month), int(date_day),
                        int(time_hour), int(date_minute), tzinfo=timezone_variable)
print(new_datetime) 
# 2020-10-21 10:21:00+01:00 
print(repr(new_datetime))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 10, 21, tzinfo=tzfile('GB-Eire'))

# with zoneinfo:
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 10, 21, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/London'))
```

Note: you can directly create a `datetime` object. If you use `pytz` (deprecated with Python 3.9), you *must* use the [localize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace) method of the timezone object. Otherwise, you'll end up with `LMT` (local mean time):

```
import pytz
timezone_variable = pytz.timezone("Europe/London")

# not what you want (most of the time...):
new_datetime = datetime(int(date_year), int(date_month), int(date_day),
                        int(time_hour), int(date_minute), tzinfo=timezone_variable)
print(repr(new_datetime))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 10, 21, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' LMT-1 day, 23:59:00 STD>)
```

---

Side-note: interestingly, `dateutil` returns the [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) `GB-Eire` time zone name for `Europe/London`. It is correct nevertheless, no worries.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is anyway to localise an aware datetime? I have a datetime that is UTC timezone, and I want to convert it to a local timezone (unknown beforehand). I get an error trying to use localise, as it says it is aware, and as you said the .replace function gives LMT.

Comment: @101892781: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64472668/10197418) ;-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for answering both, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a timezone object from a string using [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/):

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> timezone("Europe/London")
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' LMT-1 day, 23:59:00 STD>
```

This can then be used in the `datetime.datetime()` constructor as the `tzinfo` parameter. Use the `localize()` function as described in the docs if needed.