# Pytz Localise on Aware Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I am trying to convert an aware datetime (UTC) to a local time using pytz.

I was using this snippet of code, which lead to the time being off by a few minutes

```py
new_timezone = pytz.timezone(local_timezone)
new_datetime = entry[1].replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=new_timezone)
```

I tried to do this, but get an error that it is not a naive datetime:

```py
local_timezone_pytz.localize(entry[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `astimezone`, e.g.:

```
import datetime
import pytz

dt = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 5, 48, 5, 806183, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

dt_est = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
# datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 1, 48, 5, 806183, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

Note that this is not specific to `pytz`; you can also supply a timezone object from `dateutil.tz.gettz` or `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` to `astimezone`.