# How to convert datetime into GMT +7 in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like that:

```html
   conversation__created_at
0  2020-10-15T03:39:42.766773+00:00
1  2020-10-14T11:24:33.831177+00:00
2  2020-10-14T08:29:44.192258+00:00
3  2020-10-14T01:42:06.674313+00:00
4  2020-10-13T12:57:04.218184+00:00
```

How to convert it into GMT +7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a pandas series because the data you posted looks like one.
Then you can use `tz_convert`, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('2020-10-15T03:39:42.766773+00:00').tz_convert('Etc/GMT+7')
```

As pointed out in the comments, since the datetime carries a `T` in it, it is of string format, thus we need to convert to datetime first and then convert to the correct timezone.

```
pd.to_datetime(series).dt.tz_convert('Etc/GMT+7')
```

Comment: the OP's input is of dtype string since there still is the 'T' separator between date and time, so pd.to_datetime presumably is required ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes, thanks for pointing that out. I never noticed that `T` is actually indicating string fromat. I updated my answer.

Comment: oh and there's one more caveat; `'Etc/GMT+7'` is UTC-7 (not +7). not sure what the OP expects here. would be easier if a certain time zone was named.

Comment: so what's the syntax for +7 (Jakarta)?

Comment: @ab.trubex There is the timezone `Asia/Jakarta`, so you can use this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime` library only.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

d = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-10-15T03:39:42.766773+00:00")
tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=7))
new_time = d.astimezone(tz)
```

Comment: how to collaborate it in pandas? do we need for loop?

Comment: With a list of time, you can use for loop. This snippet doesn't need pandas.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pytz` to set timezone for your `datetime` instance

for example:

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()

print(date)
tz = timezone("Etc/GMT+7")
date = date.replace(tzinfo=tz)
print(date)
```

out put:

```
2020-10-26 10:33:25.934699
2020-10-26 10:33:25.934699-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply pytz.timezone on the df

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

def myDate(x): 
  tz = timezone("Etc/GMT+7")
  dt = x.replace(tzinfo=tz)
  return dt

df['conversation__created_at'] = df.apply(lambda row: myDate(row['conversation__created_at'].to_pydatetime()))
```

Comment: once more things, i add df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

Comment: besides that there is a pandas built-in for this task, I think you shouldn't suggest to use `replace` here. Although this works for static offsets, it causes wrong offsets (LMT) for actual time zones, see [pytz localize vs. replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1379740/10197418).