# Why pytz.localize and datetime.replace return different results?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

As [documentation of pytz](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/pytz/) says:

```
def localize(self, dt, is_dst=False):
    '''Convert naive time to local time'''
    if dt.tzinfo is not None:
        raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
    return dt.replace(tzinfo=self)
```

So as the last line shows, localize and dt.replace are the same. Because the algorithm above, if we remove the `if` part, is `return dt.replace(tzinfo=self)` which just use `datetime.replace`.

But we know that the output are different:

```
time = datetime.now()
tehran_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tehran')
print(tehran_tz.localize(time))
print(time.replace(tzinfo=tehran_tz))
```

Output:

2021-02-22 21:15:29.781400+03:**30**
2021-02-22 21:15:29.781400+03:**26**

It's not about which one is correct [which is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace). But why they are different while their code are the same.

Comment: [This blog entry](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) might give some insight. By the way, Python 3.9 has [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), which could help prevent some "localize-vs-replace" head aches.