# datetime.combine with timezone is different from datetime.now with timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

In the below code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

EDT = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

d1 = datetime.now(tz=EDT)

d2 = datetime.combine(d1.date(), d1.time(), tzinfo=EDT)
```

Why are *d1* and *d2* showing different timezone information?

```
>> d1
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 8, 7, 0, 44, 316514, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

```
>> d2
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 8, 7, 0, 44, 316514, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
```

How do I get the same datetime as `datetime.now` when using `datetime.combine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.now` effectively converts (localizes) your datetime with the `pytz` timezone object - from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

> If tz is not None, it must be an instance of a tzinfo subclass, and
> the current date and time are converted to tz’s time zone.

[datetime.combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) does not do that. It is as if you would write something like `datetime(2020,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))` - effectively *not adjusting* the time zone to the provided date/time. See also e.g. [pytz localize vs datetime replace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1379740/10197418) and [pytz: The Fastest Footgun in the West](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) for more background info.

The correct way to get `d2` with `pytz` would be

```
d2 = EDT.localize(datetime.combine(d1.date(), d1.time()))
```

No such issues if using timezone objects from `dateutil` or `zoneinfo` (Python 3.9+):

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

EDT = ZoneInfo('US/Eastern')
d1 = datetime.now(tz=EDT)
d2 = datetime.combine(d1.date(), d1.time(), tzinfo=EDT)

# d1
# Out[75]: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 8, 7, 57, 18, 309209, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Eastern'))

# d2
# Out[76]: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 8, 7, 57, 18, 309209, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Eastern'))

# d1 == d2
# Out[77]: True
```