# Time zones in datetime

Tags: python, datetime, replace, timezone, pytz

I am experiencing differences in the way time zone definitions are applied in `datetime.now(tzinfo=xxx)` and in the `replace` method `datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=xxx)`

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pytz

dt.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Copenhagen")).tzname() # returns "LMT"
                                                                     #  whereas 
dt.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Copenhagen")).tzname()                  # returns "CEST"
```

applying e.g `xx.astimezone(pytz.timezone("UTC"))` performs as expected in the `"CEST"`-case whereas it is one hour off in the `"LMT"` case.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Although possible without raising a warning, using `replace` with pytz timezone objects is simply wrong (except for UTC), see [docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic). Use `localize`. If you work with Python 3.9+, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) instead of pytz, it avoids the described caveat and you can safely use replace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pytz localize vs datetime replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace)

Comment: You are damn right! I didn't know that. Thanks budy and enjoy the weekend.