# Confused by datetime.datetime and timezone

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to use timezones for input to pysolar (but my question seems to be pysolar-independent).

It's 5:33pm right now. If I type

```
datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
```

I get as output

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 6, 17, 33, 0, 781951, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

However, if I type

```
datetime.datetime(2022,5,6,17,33,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
```

I get

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 6, 17, 33, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' LMT+0:09:00 STD>)
```

which seems to be almost 2 hours off (but not quite)! What am I getting wrong? What should I be typing the second time so that I get the "correct" answer, i.e., that from the first time (with datetime.datetime.now)?

Comment: I vaguely recall that you should use `pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris").localize(dt)` with a naive datetime object `dt`, instead of passing the timezone to the `tzinfo`. Not sure though since I haven't done much work with timezone-aware datetimes.

Comment: I get "NameError: name 'dt' is not defined"

Comment: Well `dt` is your naive datetime object `datetime.datetime(2022,5,6,17,33,0,0)`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127752/843953

Comment: Oh, I see. ```pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris").localize(datetime.datetime(2022,5,6,17,33,0,0))```