# Convert local time to utc in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying the following:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

date = datetime.datetime(2011,01,01) # this is in UTC time
tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
```

How would I then convert this datetime into the US/Pacific equivalent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can provide the `tzinfo` argument to the `datetime` function:

```
tz = timezone('US/Pacific')
date = datetime.datetime(2011, 01, 01, tzinfo=tz)
```

Or convert an existing datetime object to another timezone:

```
date_pacific = date.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))
```

Comment: -1: it is incorrect. Don't pass pytz timezone to `datetime()` constructor if the timezone has multiple UTC offsets (same place, different time). [Use `tz.localize()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26190657/4279).

Comment: like in US/Pacific timezone

Answer (score 1):

Its been asked before, but any way you can find it here -

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/converting-time-zones-datetime-objects-python/

If you know the hour difference to which you would like to change you can do following -

e.g. - your timezone is +2 hours to UTC

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_utc = datetime.utcnow()
my_timezone = current_utc + timedelta(hours=2)
```

Comment: the input is *local time*, not UTC time. If you know utc offset for the given local time then to convert local time to utc: `utc_time = local_time - utc_offset`