# Python: Converting string to timestamp with microseconds

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, converters

I would like to convert string date format to timestamp with microseconds 
I try the following but not giving expected result:

```
"""input string date -> 2014-08-01 04:41:52,117
expected result -> 1410748201.117"""

import time
import datetime

myDate = "2014-08-01 04:41:52,117"
timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f").timetuple())

print timestamp
> 1410748201.0
```

Where did the milliseconds go?

Comment: the input date (2014-08-01) doesn't correspond to the timestamp (2014-09-15 02:30:01.117Z)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no slot for the microseconds component in a time tuple:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> myDate = "2014-08-01 04:41:52,117"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f").timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=4, tm_min=41, tm_sec=52, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=213, tm_isdst=-1)
```

You'll have to add those manually:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) + (dt.microsecond / 1000000.0)
1406864512.117
```

The other method you could follow is to produce a [`timedelta()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) relative to the epoch, then get the timestamp with the [`timedelta.total_seconds()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
epoch = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
(dt - epoch).total_seconds()
```

The use of a *local time epoch* is quite deliberate since you have a naive (not timezone-aware) datetime  value. This method *can* be inaccurate based on the history of your local timezone however, see [J.F. Sebastian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161156/python-converting-string-to-timestamp-with-microseconds/26161653?noredirect=1#comment41015438_26161653). You'd have to convert the naive datetime value to a timezone-aware datetime value first using your local timezone before subtracting a timezone-aware epoch.

As such, it is easier to stick to the `timetuple()` + microseconds approach.

Demo:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")
>>> epoch = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
>>> (dt - epoch).total_seconds()
1406864512.117
```

Comment: **1** `(dt - epoch)` is incorrect if `dt` is a naive local time. Local time may be set back (DST transition in the fall in the northern hemisphere). Timestamp should **not** be set back in this case. **2** Also "local time epoch" might be misleading. The epoch is a *single* time instance (1970 for Python) -- it is the same around the world. If C library supports a historical timezone database or the UTC for the local timezone had the same value at the time then `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` returns local time corresponding to the epoch.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the `epoch` value uses `fromtimestamp()`, not `utcfromtimestamp()`, to handle the DST difference, precisely because the `dt` value is naive.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Had I used `utcfromtimestamp()` instead, I'd have to first make `dt` timezone aware and thus allow Python to compensate for the DST issues.

Comment: you misunderstood. The issue is that the formula uses local time. Local time may be ambiguous (there is nothing you can do if it is the input and no other info is available). And the utc offset for the local timezone may be different in the past (you need the tz database to find it). The correct formula: `ts = utc_time - epoch_in_utc = local time - utc offset(now) - epoch in local time + utc offset (then)`. Your formula is equivalent to using UTC offset as it is now i.e., it assumes `utc offset(now) == utc offset (then)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: ah, good point. The formula would be easier with a proper timezone database. As an *approximation*, ignoring historical issues, is it good enough? Because `time.time()` doesn't use historical values *either*.

Comment: `time.time()` doesn't depend on the local timezone (if we ignore systems with `'right'` timezones (it is a different time scale)). It doesn't need the historical timezone database.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.4 and later you can use

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f").timestamp()
```

This doesn't require importing the `time` module. It also uses less steps so it should be faster. For older versions of python the other provided answers are probably your best option.

However, the resulting timestamp will interpret myDate in local time, rather than UTC, which may cause issues if myDate was given in UTC

Answer (score 2):

> Where did the milliseconds go?

It is the easy part. `.timetuple()` call drops them. You could add them back using `.microsecond` attribute.  The [`datetime.timestamp()` method from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) works that way for naive datetime objects:

```
def timestamp(self):
    "Return POSIX timestamp as float"
    if self._tzinfo is None:
        return _time.mktime((self.year, self.month, self.day,
                             self.hour, self.minute, self.second,
                             -1, -1, -1)) + self.microsecond / 1e6
    else:
        return (self - _EPOCH).total_seconds()
```

It is enough if possible ~1 hour errors could be ignored in your case. I assume that you want microseconds and therefore you can't ignore ~1 hour time errors silently.

To convert the local time given as a string to the POSIX timestamp correctly is a complex task in general. You could convert the local time to UTC and then [get the timestamp from UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

There are two main issues:

- local time may be non-existent or ambiguous e.g. during DST transitions the same time may occur twice
- UTC offset for the local timezone may be different in the past and therefore a naive: [`local time minus epoch in local time` formula may fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161156/python-converting-string-to-timestamp-with-microseconds#comment41015438_26161653)

Both can be solved using the tz database (`pytz` module in Python):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

tz = get_localzone() # get pytz timezone corresponding to the local timezone

naive_d = datetime.strptime(myDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f")
# a) raise exception for non-existent or ambiguous times
d = tz.localize(naive_d, is_dst=None)
## b) assume standard time, adjust non-existent times
#d = tz.normalize(tz.localize(naive_d, is_dst=False))
## c) assume DST is in effect, adjust non-existent times
#d = tz.normalize(tz.localize(naive_d, is_dst=True))
timestamp = d - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

The result is `timestamp` -- a `timedelta` object, you can convert it to seconds, milliseconds, etc.

Also different systems may behave differently around/during leap seconds. Most application can ignore that they exist.

In general, it might be simpler to store POSIX timestamps *in addition* to the local time instead of trying to guess it from the local time.

Comment: Note: `datetime.timestamp` is only available in Python 3; the OP is using Python 2 (judging by the `print` statements).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have *not* suggested to use `.timestamp()` method. I just use it as an example (flawed) implementation.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest you did. I am only pointing out that the method doesn't exist in Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand *what* you said. I don't understand *why* you said it. It doesn't matter in this case that the code happens to be included in Python 3 stdlib `+ d.microsecond / 1e6` works the same way on Python 2 and 3.